# ¿Cómo capturar el Response de una API en un objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

He intentado esta función:

```
response.data.token = new Object();
for (i = 0; i <= response.data.token.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= producto.modulo.length; j++) {
        console.log(modulo); 
    }
}

response = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
console.log(response);
```

Pero no me quiere funcionar.

Comment: En ese trozo de código no se ve la parte donde haces la petición. Para poder ayudarte tendrás que añadir la parte donde haces la petición.

Comment: Hola @user124706, este tipo de pregunta es demasiado vago, creo que deberías agregar mas detalles , mira [ask] para mas detalle, otro problema que tengo es que ese código no veo por donde se comunica con una api. y si no sabes como, te recomiendo [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)